# Angular - I'm referencing all JS files in index.html - is this ok?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started building my first AngularJS app.

I've been following a tutorial where it demonstrated on one controller adding everything in.

Now however I want to build on that so would like to seperate my controllers and services.

I easily seperated the services and controllers into seperate JS files and also realised that in my index.html i need to reference those JS files.

Is this the 'best practice' way? I'm feeling uneasy about listing so many js files in my index.html, feels untidy?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is valid. On one hand, having everything in separate files is a lot more maintainable. On the other, loading 100s of files slows the page down (for example, Chrome only loads... five (?) files at once, and if you have more than that, the page will slow down while it loads the rest).

I would look into software such as [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), which you could use to concatenate all your files into one large build file, which can then be minified through the same software.

Comment: Cool. So i'm actually Gulp already with SaSS so i guess could just build on that. But in terms of best practice for AngularJS?

Comment: Angular itself doesn't care about how many files you split it into, to my knowledge. Our app has about 80 js files that we merge into a build file (we also build on Angular) and we haven't had any problems with this (other than some minor minification woes which were pretty easy to fix).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at lazy loading angular modules and controllers using ocLazyload? and it works well with `ui-router`. You can find more details about ocLazyload at https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs